# Validate Date Format in changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to validate the date with this format `MM/dd/yyyy` with this in my changeset

```
|> validate_format(:birth_date, ~r/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/)

field :birth_date, Ecto.Date
```

But, I'm getting an error of

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Kernel.=~/2
 stacktrace:
   (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:1580: Kernel.=~(#Ecto.Date<2010-04-17>, ~r/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/)
   (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1357: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Changeset.validate_format/4
   (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1236: Ecto.Changeset.validate_change/3
   test/models/person_test.exs:10: (test)
```

Any idea or this cant be done in [Ecto.Date](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Date.html)? Thank you.

Comment: A date is not a string; you cannot validate a Date with a regex. If you're using `cast()` earlier that should do this validation as well as conversion to Ecto.Date automatically. Does that not work for you?